Real numbers extend to complex numbers. Why do (real) integers extend to 'Gaussian integers' instead of 'complex integers'?
Real numbers extend to complex numbers are $\mathbb C := \{ a+bi;a,b \in \mathbb R \}$. So why isn't the set $\{a+bi;a,b \in \mathbb Z \}$ called complex integers instead of Gaussian integers, an extension of (real) integers? Or why isn't $\mathbb C$ instead $\mathbb G$ and called 'Gaussian numbers' ?

“One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand." — Feynman

Gaussian integers are called integers, so there is no problem. Actually, $\Bbb Z[i]$ is the ring of integers in the finite extension $\Bbb Q(i)\mid \Bbb Q$, so we do not really consider $\Bbb C$, but only the number field $\Bbb Q(i)$. So "complex integers" is not what we mean.

Wikipedia: 'The complex plane is sometimes known as the Argand plane or Gauss plane.' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane Cool.

@littleO Do you disagree with Dietrich Burde ?

There really is no mathematical "why" for naming conventions. This choice honors Gauss, who studied the arithmetic of the (now named) Gaussian integers.
Gauss was an early explorer of $\mathbb{C}$ but not unique enough in that capacity to warrant  $\mathbb{G}$.
